# Installers take forever to prompt

Tags: windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10. There's like a 50% chance that when I click to execute a .msi or .exe installer I just downloaded through Chrome that it will take 10 minutes before I get the UAC prompt.

Same thing happens if I double-click the icon in Explorer. My icon turns to an hour glass for a half second, and then it doesn't do anything.

Some time later after I've forgotten about it, a UAC prompt will appear. Usually 2 or 3 of them because I've clicked the icon so many darn times -- they all appear at once. After it appears, everything is snappy -- I can step through the wizard and finish installing without problems.

I don't know if it's quietly scanning the program, or checking permissions or what, but it's preventing me from getting work done.

How do I fix this?

---

I'm trying to run the .msi from PowerShell (not sure if I can do this) but it also hangs. No output. Doesn't show the next prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the system is creating a Restore Point *before it actually starts installing the software*. You can examine existing Restore Points from the Control Panel, or using the free [*Restore Point Creator*](http://www.toms-world.org/blog/restore_point_creator).

It often takes minutes to create a Restore Point, but just seconds for the installation itself. However, I find the convenience of being able to backtrack from an aberrant application installation or update outweighs the inconvenience of the wait.

It is also possible that an anti-malware application is scanning and/or checking VirusTotal before starting the installation. You could determine that, **with some risk**, by temporarily disabling the AV.

Comment: "Minutes"? Like 25+ minutes? I was still waiting for my .msi to load 25 minutes after I made this post. I gave up and rebooted. Windows said it was installing some updates. I'm wondering if it was quietly installing while it was running too and holding up the installer I actually wanted to run. I know in previous versions of Windows you could only run one installer at a time. After I rebooted, the .msi installed right away. So I think something was blocking it... I'll keep an eye out for restore points next time.

Comment: As you state, I've seen a message that I could not install an application while Windows Update or other application that uses the MSI framework is busy. Perhaps Windows is going through a slew of updates.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot here, but is it possible you have either Folder Redirection on, or are using a mounted folder for your AppData under the account you are logged in with? I have seen this sort of behavior before when someone was running a sluggish network connection and redirecting their profile to a network share.

Comment: Answers should really be reserved for definitive solutions.  Clarifying questions, diagnostic suggestions, and speculative solutions are more appropriate in a comment.

Comment: I don't mind the speculative solutions. A couple times people have been right on the money. It's the things you don't think to check that are often the problem. However, that wasn't the case here. None of my folders were mounted on HDDs outside my PC. The problem has gone away since Aug 2015 though. I can't remember if I did a re-install or something since then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback fixer1234. I'll keep that in mind in the future!